# Error 403 on Form submission by GET Method

Tags: php, get

My PHP-MySql website was recently deployed on server.

After uploading to server, whenever I submit forms using **GET Method**, I get **Error 403**.
But when I change all the code related to that form to POST, it starts working.

But I need it to work with GET Method. How do I fix this?

Comment: It may be only accessable by post not get.

Comment: Can you please show us the code with an example

Comment: Try a simple form that submits to a page that dumps $_GET.   To me this sounds like a url/rewrite/routing issue.

Comment: Seems like your url contains forbidden characters. check server settings